# Get all dynamic media scene7 URL from Asset object in AEM

Tags: java, aem, assets

Why is the asset.listRenditions() function in AEM only returning Static renditions and not Dynamic renditions, even though I can confirm the presence of Dynamic renditions for the asset in the AEM Asset manager?

Java Code Snap:
[image]

Asset Renditions: We are only getting Static Renditions and original rendition but not Dynamic.

[image]

Comment: Hy, please [don't upload text, code, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Please edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the JCR structure I can see that static renditions are saved in subnodes of the asset, whereas *Dynamic Media* renditions are stored in the CDN and the respective resource IDs end up in the *metadata* node as properties ("dam:scene7...")
My 2 cents are that the `Asset.listRenditions` is legacy code that has not been updated yet to handle other renditions than the statically and locally rendered ones.

Answer (score 0):

From personal experience, you better create your own class to read the metadata properties to get the URLs you need.